# Whitespace created in csname

Tags: macros

I am using the `newfile` package to use an input file to insert figures, headings etc. Everything works fine, but a whitespace is created after the variable which is a problem if that variable represents a figure name that must be included in the tex file. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % Default font size is 12pt, it can be changed here

\usepackage{geometry} % Required to change the page size to A4
\geometry{a4paper} % Set the page size to be A4 as opposed to the default US Letter

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures

\usepackage{float} % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture

\usepackage{newfile}

\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored



\begin{document}

%Define the file read object
\newread\productin
%Open auxillary file and stream relevant variables

\immediate\openin\productin=aux_files/femara.tex  %this filename must change according to relevant report
\newcounter{linenr}
\loop\unless\ifeof\productin
\stepcounter{linenr}
\immediate\read\productin t\expandafter o\csname var\alph{linenr}\endcsname
\repeat
\immediate\closein\productin


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page



\HRule \\[0.8cm]
{ \huge \bfseries \varc Analytics Report for \vara}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[2cm]

\textsc{\LARGE \varb}\\[12cm] % Report month

\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Prepared by:}\\
\textsc{Umami Consulting} \\[0.4cm]
{\large \today}\\[3cm]
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} 


%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a logo - this will require the graphicx package

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Include a table of contents

\newpage % Begins the essay on a new page instead of on the same page as the table of contents 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REPORT OVERVIEW
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Report Overview} % Major section
\subsection{Subsection 1} % Sub-section

\begin{figure}[H] % Example image
\center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{\vard}}
\caption{Example image.}
\label{fig:speciation}
\end{figure}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Conclusion} % Major section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{thebibliography}{99} % Bibliography - this is intentionally simple in this template

\bibitem[Figueredo and Wolf, 2009]{Figueredo:2009dg}
Figueredo, A.~J. and Wolf, P. S.~A. (2009).
\newblock Assortative pairing and life history strategy - a cross-cultural
  study.
\newblock {\em Human Nature}, 20:317--330.

\end{thebibliography}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Input file content (`femara.tex`)

```
June 2014
Data
Plt_Province
```

My problem is that `\vara` produces `Area`   instead of `Area`. My input file doesn't have whitespaces after the variable names.

Any idea how to strip the whitespace?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [MWE - Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

The trailing space is due to the end-of-line characters in the input file.

The simplest workaround is to remove it altogether by setting (temporarily)

```
\endlinechar=-1
```

Here's a full example, where I stripped off the irrelevant things, but added a safety measure for the underscore (you possibly don't need it). I also changed the input file to `\jobname.dat` just to avoid clobbering my own files.

Note that `\immediate` makes sense only for writing out files, not for reading them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for printing the underscore

\newcounter{linenr}

\begin{document}

%Define the file read object
\newread\productin
%Open auxiliary file and stream relevant variables
\openin\productin=\jobname.dat % <--------- use the real name here
\chardef\savedendlinechar=\endlinechar\endlinechar=-1
\chardef\saveduscatcode=\catcode`\_ \catcode`\_=12 % protect the underscore
\setcounter{linenr}{0}
\loop\unless\ifeof\productin
  \stepcounter{linenr}
  \read\productin to \next
  \expandafter\let\csname var\alph{linenr}\endcsname\next
\repeat
\closein\productin
\endlinechar=\savedendlinechar % restore the endlinechar
\catcode`\_=\saveduscatcode % restore the usual underscore

\vara

\varb

\varc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an `expl3` implementation that allows to change the prefix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for printing the underscore
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\readfile}{ O{var} m}
 {
  \alta_readfile_to:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_alta_readfile_line_int
\ior_new:N \g_alta_readfile_file_stream

\cs_new_protected:Npn \alta_readfile_to:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_alta_readfile_line_int
  % link the input stream to the file
  \ior_open:Nn \g_alta_readfile_file_stream { #2 }
  % loop through the input stream
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_alta_readfile_file_stream
   {
    % step the line counter
    \int_incr:N \l_alta_readfile_line_int
    % define '#1a', '#1b' and so on (default for #1 is var)
    \tl_set:cn 
     {
      #1\int_to_alph:n { \l_alta_readfile_line_int }
     }
     { \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } } % the input line is stringified
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readfile{\jobname.dat}

\vara

\varb

\varc

\readfile[foo]{\jobname.dat}

\fooa

\foob

\fooc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I agree, using an underscore in the variable parameters is maybe not the best practice. But good to know your solution is robust enough to handle it.